# How to reactively generate additional rhandsontable tables for user inputs with click of an action button in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I've been using action buttons to add columns to a series of linked `rhandsontable` tables in R Shiny. Now, however, I'm trying to figure out how to generate additional `rhandsontable` table templates with the click of an action button. Is this possible? Each added table needs to be independent of the other tables, in the sense of allowing the user to input and store values into the added tables that are independent of the other tables although the "blank" new tables that are added can share a common base template form. The "base table" shown in the below code (`uiTable1`, `hottable1`) can never be deleted by a user. The below code shows what I started but the action button doesn't yet work.

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c('A','B','C','Sum') 
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, 'Col 1' = c(1,1,0,2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable1'),br(),    # generates base table, can never be deleted by user
  actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"),br()  # adds table
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable1 <- reactiveVal(data1)            # base table can never be deleted by user
  
  # records changes to base table and will need same for added tables:
  observeEvent(input$hottable1,{uiTable1(hot_to_r(input$hottable1))})
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  # counts nbr of tables added by user clicks of addTbl action button:
  cntAdds = reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$addTbl,{
    cntAdds(cntAdds()+1) 
  })
  
  # adds column summation to last row of table, will need for all added tables too:
  observe({
    req(input$hottable1)
    DF <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
    DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"),]
    DF["Sum",] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"),, drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
    uiTable1(DF)
  })

  # Pending: observer adds new table
  # observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
  #   newTbl1 <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
  #   names(newTbl1) <- paste("Tbl", hot_to_r(cntAdds()))
  #   uiTable1(cbind(uiTable1(), newTbl1))
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Regarding this I'd suggest to take a look at [shiny's modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below appears to do the trick, with an abundance of explanatory comments:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("hottable1"),       # undeletable base table
  actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"),    # adds new table
  tags$div(id = "placeholder")            # using div for insertUI selector is more stable
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTbl1 <- reactiveValues(base = data1)  # undeletable base table
  rv <- reactiveValues()                  # used for dynamic table add/removal
  
  # records changes to base table:
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {
    uiTbl1$base <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
  })
  
  # used to render changed base table:
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTbl1$base, rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  # adds column sum to last row of base table (same function for added tables further down):
  observe({
    req(input$hottable1)
    DF <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
    DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), ]
    DF["Sum", ] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), , drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
    uiTbl1$base <- DF
  })
  
  # dynamically add/remove tables:
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- gsub("\\.", "", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%OS3")) # system time at add used as table ID
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "DT")
    btnID <- paste0(divID, "rmv")
    uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]] <- data1 # captures initial dataframe values
    
    # renders table delete button and added table in UI:
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = divID,
        actionButton(btnID, "Remove table", class = "pull-left btn btn-danger"),
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID),
        hr()
      )
    )
    # server section for added table:
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]], rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
    })
    
    # adds column summation to last row of added table:
    observeEvent(input[[dtID]], {
      DF <- hot_to_r(input[[dtID]])
      DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), ]
      DF["Sum", ] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), , drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
      uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]] <- DF # update the table with the sum
    })
    
    # remove table from the app when remove button clicked:
    observeEvent(input[[btnID]],{
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", divID))
      rv[[divID]] <- NULL
      uiTbl1[[paste0(divID,"tbl")]] <- NULL
      },
      ignoreInit = TRUE,
      once = TRUE
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```